# TX Text Editor control in HTML5 and WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing, txtextcontrol

I am new to TXTEXT COntrol editor. I am exploring the features of it but I notice that its an asp.net control. Can I use it in HTML5 and bind it through JSON without using ASPx.cs ? I am using WEB API with HTML5, JSON and JS

Most of the examples I went through the TXTEXT control is strongly coupled with ASPx.cs page. If txTextcontrol works with WEB API with HTML5 can you please redirect me to some working examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I added the textcontrol to a form like so:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <!--main controller-->
        <cc1:TextControl ID="TextControl1" runat="server" Dock="Fill" />
    </div>
```

Some examples here:
http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/blog/archive/20150123/
This is one example but you can search for what you are interested in. Most example are for Windows Forms but you will find for asp.net also if you dig.
You can also look into the TXTextControl help file for full documentation which also contains a section called ASP.NED user guide (I presume that you downloaded and installed the trial version)